Why does multiplying rotation values in Unity C# script cause unexpected behavior
I created the following Unity C# script and attached it to a Cube object. The following code only rotates around the Y-axis. When this code is attached, the Cube rotates smoothly.
using UnityEngine;

public class CubeRotation : MonoBehaviour
{
    float[] y_values = new float[] {179f, 179f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 179f, 179f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 179f, 179f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 179f, 179f, -180f, -180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 180f, 180f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 180f, 180f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 180f, 180f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, -180f, -180f, -180f, -180f, -180f, -180f, -180f, -180f, -180f, -180f, -179f, -179f, -179f, -179f, -179f, -179f, -179f, -179f, -179f, -179f, -179f, -179f, -179f, -179f, -178f, -178f, -178f, -178f, -177f, -177f, -177f, -177f, -177f, -177f, -176f, -176f, -175f, -175f, -175f, -175f, -175f, -175f, -172f, -172f, -172f, -172f, -171f, -171f, -169f, -169f, -168f, -168f, -167f, -167f, -167f, -167f, -165f, -165f, -164f, -164f, -163f, -163f, -163f, -163f, -163f, -163f, -160f, -160f, -159f, -159f, -159f, -159f, -159f, -159f, -156f, -156f, -154f, -154f, -153f, -153f, -153f, -153f, -150f, -150f, -149f, -149f, -149f, -149f, -149f, -149f, -149f, -149f, -149f, -149f, -149f, -149f, -146f, -146f, -146f, -146f, -147f, -147f, -144f, -144f, -144f, -144f, -144f, -144f, -144f, -144f, -144f, -144f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -141f, -141f, -141f, -141f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -143f, -143f, -144f, -144f, -145f, -145f, -145f, -145f, -145f, -145f, -145f, -145f, -146f, -146f, -146f, -146f, -146f, -146f, -147f, -147f, -147f, -147f, -147f, -147f, -149f, -149f, -150f, -150f, -151f, -151f, -151f, -151f, -151f, -151f, -151f, -151f, -154f, -154f, -155f, -155f, -156f, -156f, -156f, -156f, -159f, -159f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -164f, -164f, -165f, -165f, -165f, -165f, -168f, -168f, -169f, -169f, -169f, -169f, -169f, -169f, -174f, -174f, -175f, -175f, -175f, -175f, -175f, -175f, -175f, -175f, -179f, -179f, -179f, -179f, -180f, -180f, -180f, -180f, 178f, 178f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 174f, 174f, 172f, 172f, 172f, 172f, 172f, 172f, 168f, 168f, 167f, 167f, 167f, 167f, 167f, 167f, 164f, 164f, 163f, 163f, 163f, 163f, 163f, 163f, 163f, 163f, 163f, 163f, 161f, 161f, 161f, 161f, 160f, 160f, 160f, 160f, 158f, 158f, 158f, 158f, 158f, 158f, 158f, 158f, 157f, 157f, 157f, 157f, 157f, 157f, 157f, 157f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 157f, 157f, 157f, 157f, 158f, 158f, 158f, 158f, 160f, 160f, 161f, 161f, 161f, 161f, 161f, 161f, 164f, 164f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 168f, 168f, 168f, 168f, 169f, 169f, 169f, 169f, 172f, 172f, 173f, 173f, 173f, 173f, 173f, 173f, 176f, 176f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 179f, 179f, 180f, 180f, -180f, -180f, -180f, -180f, -177f, -177f, -176f, -176f, -176f, -176f, -176f, -176f, -174f, -174f, -173f, -173f, -173f, -173f, -173f, -173f, -170f, -170f, -169f, -169f, -169f, -169f, -169f, -169f, -168f, -168f, -168f, -168f, -168f, -168f, -167f, -167f, -167f, -167f, -167f, -167f, -167f, -167f, -167f, -167f, -166f, -166f, -166f, -166f, -166f, -166f, -165f, -165f, -165f, -165f, -165f, -165f, -165f, -165f, -165f, -165f, -164f, -164f, -164f, -164f, -164f, -164f, -164f, -164f, -164f, -164f, -164f, -164f, -163f, -163f, -163f, -163f, -163f, -163f, -162f, -162f, -162f, -162f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -162f, -162f, -162f, -162f, -162f, -162f, -163f, -163f, -163f, -163f, -163f, -163f, -163f, -163f, -164f, -164f, -165f, -165f, -165f, -165f, -165f, -165f, -167f, -167f, -168f, -168f, -169f, -169f, -169f, -169f, -171f, -171f, -172f, -172f, -173f, -173f, -176f, -176f, -177f, -177f, -177f, -177f, -177f, -177f, -179f, -179f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 179f, 179f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 174f, 174f, 173f, 173f, 173f, 173f, 173f, 173f, 171f, 171f, 170f, 170f, 170f, 170f, 170f, 170f, 168f, 168f, 168f, 168f, 168f, 168f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 167f, 167f, 167f, 167f, 167f, 167f, 167f, 167f, 167f, 167f, 167f, 167f, 167f, 167f, 168f, 168f, 168f, 168f, 168f, 168f, 169f, 169f, 169f, 169f, 169f, 169f, 170f, 170f, 170f, 170f, 170f, 170f, 171f, 171f, 172f, 172f, 172f, 172f, 173f, 173f, 174f, 174f, 174f, 174f, 175f, 175f, 175f, 175f, 176f, 176f, 176f, 176f, 176f, 176f, 176f, 176f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 178f, 178f, 178f, 178f, 178f, 178f, 177f, 177f, 178f, 178f, 178f, 178f, 178f, 178f, 178f, 178f};
    int i = 0;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (i < y_values.Length)
        {
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, y_values[i], 0.0f);
            i++;
        }
    }
}

However, when I multiply the value by y_values[i] * 0.6f, the rotation behavior becomes strange. I expected the rotation to simply decrease, but that is not the case.
using UnityEngine;

public class CubeRotation : MonoBehaviour
{
    float[] y_values = new float[] {179f, 179f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 179f, 179f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 179f, 179f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 179f, 179f, -180f, -180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 180f, 180f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 180f, 180f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 180f, 180f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 179f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, -180f, -180f, -180f, -180f, -180f, -180f, -180f, -180f, -180f, -180f, -179f, -179f, -179f, -179f, -179f, -179f, -179f, -179f, -179f, -179f, -179f, -179f, -179f, -179f, -178f, -178f, -178f, -178f, -177f, -177f, -177f, -177f, -177f, -177f, -176f, -176f, -175f, -175f, -175f, -175f, -175f, -175f, -172f, -172f, -172f, -172f, -171f, -171f, -169f, -169f, -168f, -168f, -167f, -167f, -167f, -167f, -165f, -165f, -164f, -164f, -163f, -163f, -163f, -163f, -163f, -163f, -160f, -160f, -159f, -159f, -159f, -159f, -159f, -159f, -156f, -156f, -154f, -154f, -153f, -153f, -153f, -153f, -150f, -150f, -149f, -149f, -149f, -149f, -149f, -149f, -149f, -149f, -149f, -149f, -149f, -149f, -146f, -146f, -146f, -146f, -147f, -147f, -144f, -144f, -144f, -144f, -144f, -144f, -144f, -144f, -144f, -144f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -141f, -141f, -141f, -141f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -142f, -143f, -143f, -144f, -144f, -145f, -145f, -145f, -145f, -145f, -145f, -145f, -145f, -146f, -146f, -146f, -146f, -146f, -146f, -147f, -147f, -147f, -147f, -147f, -147f, -149f, -149f, -150f, -150f, -151f, -151f, -151f, -151f, -151f, -151f, -151f, -151f, -154f, -154f, -155f, -155f, -156f, -156f, -156f, -156f, -159f, -159f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -164f, -164f, -165f, -165f, -165f, -165f, -168f, -168f, -169f, -169f, -169f, -169f, -169f, -169f, -174f, -174f, -175f, -175f, -175f, -175f, -175f, -175f, -175f, -175f, -179f, -179f, -179f, -179f, -180f, -180f, -180f, -180f, 178f, 178f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 174f, 174f, 172f, 172f, 172f, 172f, 172f, 172f, 168f, 168f, 167f, 167f, 167f, 167f, 167f, 167f, 164f, 164f, 163f, 163f, 163f, 163f, 163f, 163f, 163f, 163f, 163f, 163f, 161f, 161f, 161f, 161f, 160f, 160f, 160f, 160f, 158f, 158f, 158f, 158f, 158f, 158f, 158f, 158f, 157f, 157f, 157f, 157f, 157f, 157f, 157f, 157f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 156f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 154f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 155f, 157f, 157f, 157f, 157f, 158f, 158f, 158f, 158f, 160f, 160f, 161f, 161f, 161f, 161f, 161f, 161f, 164f, 164f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 168f, 168f, 168f, 168f, 169f, 169f, 169f, 169f, 172f, 172f, 173f, 173f, 173f, 173f, 173f, 173f, 176f, 176f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 179f, 179f, 180f, 180f, -180f, -180f, -180f, -180f, -177f, -177f, -176f, -176f, -176f, -176f, -176f, -176f, -174f, -174f, -173f, -173f, -173f, -173f, -173f, -173f, -170f, -170f, -169f, -169f, -169f, -169f, -169f, -169f, -168f, -168f, -168f, -168f, -168f, -168f, -167f, -167f, -167f, -167f, -167f, -167f, -167f, -167f, -167f, -167f, -166f, -166f, -166f, -166f, -166f, -166f, -165f, -165f, -165f, -165f, -165f, -165f, -165f, -165f, -165f, -165f, -164f, -164f, -164f, -164f, -164f, -164f, -164f, -164f, -164f, -164f, -164f, -164f, -163f, -163f, -163f, -163f, -163f, -163f, -162f, -162f, -162f, -162f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -160f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -161f, -162f, -162f, -162f, -162f, -162f, -162f, -163f, -163f, -163f, -163f, -163f, -163f, -163f, -163f, -164f, -164f, -165f, -165f, -165f, -165f, -165f, -165f, -167f, -167f, -168f, -168f, -169f, -169f, -169f, -169f, -171f, -171f, -172f, -172f, -173f, -173f, -176f, -176f, -177f, -177f, -177f, -177f, -177f, -177f, -179f, -179f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 180f, 179f, 179f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 174f, 174f, 173f, 173f, 173f, 173f, 173f, 173f, 171f, 171f, 170f, 170f, 170f, 170f, 170f, 170f, 168f, 168f, 168f, 168f, 168f, 168f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 165f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 166f, 167f, 167f, 167f, 167f, 167f, 167f, 167f, 167f, 167f, 167f, 167f, 167f, 167f, 167f, 168f, 168f, 168f, 168f, 168f, 168f, 169f, 169f, 169f, 169f, 169f, 169f, 170f, 170f, 170f, 170f, 170f, 170f, 171f, 171f, 172f, 172f, 172f, 172f, 173f, 173f, 174f, 174f, 174f, 174f, 175f, 175f, 175f, 175f, 176f, 176f, 176f, 176f, 176f, 176f, 176f, 176f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 177f, 178f, 178f, 178f, 178f, 178f, 178f, 177f, 177f, 178f, 178f, 178f, 178f, 178f, 178f, 178f, 178f};
    int i = 0;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (i < y_values.Length)
        {
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, y_values[i]*0.6f, 0.0f);
            i++;
        }
    }
}

Why is this happening? How can I create a script to reduce the amount of rotation?

You have both positive and negative angles in the array. You should move the logical zero rotation (currently 180?) to be at zero.

also doing almost half rotations a frame seems... a bit fast

The problem is that you're using -180 to 180 degrees for rotations, like so:

This makes it so when you multiply by 0.6, the negatives go one way around the circle, and the positives go the other way:

Just make the angles use 0-360 instead. If you don't want to fix the array manually, you can just add 360 before doing the multiplication:
transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, (y_values[i] + 360) * 0.6f, 0.0f);

